# Asp.net Source Code Compare Software

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to compare two asp.net sources and find different could you introduce me a software inside or outside of visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare (Trialware) or WinMerge

http://winmerge.org/

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: Ohhh I love Beyond Compare! +1

Answer (score 1):

kdiff is an awesome tool.. definitely check it out.. and the best part is it is open source. integrates with VCS tools while resolving conflicts.. its a pretty cool tool..

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Perforce Visual Merge and Diff Tools](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html).